# How to use "tri2a" and "tri2b_mmi" training in kaldi for dummies tutorial?

Tags: speech-recognition, kaldi

I have done **Kaldi** for dummies tutorial with my own custom audio data. In that tutorial they were using **Mono alignment** and **tri1** training method. Can i change it to **tri2a/tri2b_mmi** training?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.
In the run shell script change *ac_model_type* to either *tri2a* or *tri2b_mmi*

```
# Change this to "tri2a" if you like to test using a ML-trained model
ac_model_type=tri2b_mmi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used run.sh, then edit the file and see which directory has been set to save tri model. You can edit the code there.

Or if you are following it line by line, then make sure you set the directory in the scripts correctly like exp/tri2 or something like that